# GRPC TLS Server example for Java

Tags: grpc-java

The [HelloWorldServer TLS example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/examples/example-tls/src/main/java/io/grpc/examples/helloworldtls/HelloWorldServerTls.java)

uses the API:

```
server = Grpc.newServerBuilderForPort(port, tlscredentials)
         .addService(new GreeterImpl())
         .build();
```

However, this API does not allow for specification of timeouts. The Netty based API allows for such timeouts. For example:

```
server = NettyServerBuilder.forPort(port)
        .channelType(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
        .permitKeepAliveTime(timeout)       // can specify keepalive parameters
        .permitKeepAliveWithoutCalls(true)  // can specify keepalive parameters
        .addService(new GreeterImpl())
        .sslContext(getSslContextBuilder().build())
        .build();
```

The example code looks cleaner, but I could not find an easy way to specify keepalive parameters. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Because `Grpc.newServerBuilderForPort()` return type is declared as `ServerBuilder` whereas the methods you want are available in `NettyServerBuilder`. You can get the builder and check for its type as follows:

```
ServerBuilder<?> builder = Grpc.newServerBuilderForPort(port, tlscredentials);

if (builder instanceof NettyServerBuilder) {
   NettyServerBuilder nsBuilder = (NettyServerBuilder)builder;
   builder = nsBuilder
     .channelType(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
     .permitKeepAliveTime(timeout)       // can specify keepalive parameters
     .permitKeepAliveWithoutCalls(true);  // can specify keepalive parameters
}
server = builder.addService(new GreeterImpl()).build();
```

You don't need to set the sslContext since you have used `tlsCredentials`.